# Hadoop - No route to host while configuring HUE

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop, hue

I have installed `hue` on my local ubuntu system and installed `hadoop` muti cluster system on two system.

```
Hadoop Version : 2.7.3
Hue Version :  3.12.0
Ozzie Version : 4.3.0
```

I am facing issue when I am running `sqoop` job process from `mysql` to import data from `HDFS`. I am getting following error.

```
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No Route to Host from  Developer4/127.0.0.1 to cm:10020 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/NoRouteToHost
```

HDFS url  hdfs://master:9000

My /etc/hosts  file like

```
192.168.1.149  master
127.0.0.1 developer4
192.168.1.161  slave
```

Please suggest me where I am doing wrong. Even `ozzie` command  for start and stop command work properly on command line.

[image: Error Image Screen Shot]

Comment: Port `10020` belongs to `JobHistoryServer`.But what is `cm`? Your `/etc/hosts` has no entry for hostname `cm`.

Comment: may I know, why this question is downvoted? please provide explaination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `Hadoop` in your localhost system then you need to remove or modified below things in `core-site.xml` file.

```
mapreduce.jobhistory.address 0.0.0.0:10020 Host and port for Job History Server (default 0.0.0.0:10020)
```

After that you need to run `jobhistoryservice` with below command.

```
sbin/mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh --config /home/developer4/hadoop-2.7.3/etc start historyserver
```

After this command port is enable on your localhost and hope this will help you.

Comment: where to find core-site.xml file? I already have hadoop installed

Comment: you can able to find on following path  hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml